# Fetching specific Json data with NSDictionnary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I would like to fetch specific values in NSDictionnary with json data.
I would like to only fetch the first value for key "windspeedMiles" for example (in current_condition).
My Json data I've fetch is :

```
{
  "data": {
    "nearest_area": [
      {
        "distance_miles": "0.0",
        "latitude": "54.500",
        "longitude": "-8.500"
      }
    ],
    "request": [
      {
        "query": "Lat 54.50 and Lon -8.50",
        "type": "LatLon"
      }
    ],
    "weather": [
      {
        "date": "2014-12-09",
        "hourly": [
          {
            "cloudcover": "59",
            "humidity": "84",
            "precipMM": "0.1",
            "pressure": "1024",
            "sigHeight_m": "3.1",
            "swellDir": "290",
            "swellHeight_m": "3.0",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "12.6",
            "tempC": "5",
            "tempF": "41",
            "time": "0",
            "visibility": "10",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "116",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "SSW",
            "winddirDegree": "204",
            "windspeedKmph": "34",
            "windspeedMiles": "21"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "84",
            "humidity": "87",
            "precipMM": "0.1",
            "pressure": "1020",
            "sigHeight_m": "0.6",
            "swellDir": "240",
            "swellHeight_m": "0.1",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "12.4",
            "tempC": "6",
            "tempF": "42",
            "time": "300",
            "visibility": "10",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "119",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "SSW",
            "winddirDegree": "193",
            "windspeedKmph": "45",
            "windspeedMiles": "28"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "75",
            "humidity": "91",
            "precipMM": "0.4",
            "pressure": "1016",
            "sigHeight_m": "3.1",
            "swellDir": "290",
            "swellHeight_m": "3.0",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "11.3",
            "tempC": "7",
            "tempF": "44",
            "time": "600",
            "visibility": "2",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "266",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "SSW",
            "winddirDegree": "193",
            "windspeedKmph": "54",
            "windspeedMiles": "34"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "0",
            "humidity": "93",
            "precipMM": "0.8",
            "pressure": "1011",
            "sigHeight_m": "1.0",
            "swellDir": "250",
            "swellHeight_m": "0.2",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "10.6",
            "tempC": "16",
            "tempF": "61",
            "time": "900",
            "visibility": "10",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "SSW",
            "winddirDegree": "202",
            "windspeedKmph": "62",
            "windspeedMiles": "39"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "98",
            "humidity": "95",
            "precipMM": "6.6",
            "pressure": "1006",
            "sigHeight_m": "3.7",
            "swellDir": "290",
            "swellHeight_m": "3.6",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "11.0",
            "tempC": "18",
            "tempF": "65",
            "time": "1200",
            "visibility": "7",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "302",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0018_cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "winddirDegree": "220",
            "windspeedKmph": "64",
            "windspeedMiles": "40"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "89",
            "humidity": "95",
            "precipMM": "8.3",
            "pressure": "1003",
            "sigHeight_m": "4.3",
            "swellDir": "290",
            "swellHeight_m": "4.0",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "10.9",
            "tempC": "19",
            "tempF": "65",
            "time": "1500",
            "visibility": "5",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "308",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0018_cloudy_with_heavy_rain.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "winddirDegree": "234",
            "windspeedKmph": "60",
            "windspeedMiles": "38"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "49",
            "humidity": "73",
            "precipMM": "1.5",
            "pressure": "1004",
            "sigHeight_m": "5.7",
            "swellDir": "290",
            "swellHeight_m": "5.3",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "10.8",
            "tempC": "7",
            "tempF": "45",
            "time": "1800",
            "visibility": "10",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "353",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "W",
            "winddirDegree": "261",
            "windspeedKmph": "66",
            "windspeedMiles": "41"
          },
          {
            "cloudcover": "58",
            "humidity": "73",
            "precipMM": "0.5",
            "pressure": "1005",
            "sigHeight_m": "7.2",
            "swellDir": "290",
            "swellHeight_m": "6.7",
            "swellPeriod_secs": "10.6",
            "tempC": "5",
            "tempF": "42",
            "time": "2100",
            "visibility": "10",
            "waterTemp_C": "12",
            "waterTemp_F": "53",
            "weatherCode": "353",
            "weatherIconUrl": [
              {
                "value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png"
              }
            ],
            "winddir16Point": "W",
            "winddirDegree": "260",
            "windspeedKmph": "79",
            "windspeedMiles": "49"
          }
        ],
        "maxtempC": "19",
        "mintempC": "5"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my code :

Reports.m :

```
#import "Reports.h"

@interface Reports ()

@end

@implementation Reports

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Bundoran&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=e1caa114b7fba6f5bcea272e1fc77"];

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSDictionary *dico = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSDictionary *wind = [dico objectForKey:@"windspeedMiles"];
        NSLog(@"The current windspeedMiles is : %@", wind);

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Comment: Ok. What's your question?

Comment: @Madbreaks I would like to only fetch the first value for key "windspeedMiles" for example (in current_condition). My NSLog sends me : "nil" and I want that sends me the value in current_condition i.e. : "19"

Comment: So, you've got the JSON layout.  The Objective-C object layout will be the same after parsing with NSJSONSerialization.  Just access through the levels and get the data.

Comment: So, what key values are directly contained in the `dico` dictionary??

Comment: Off-topic because you're asking to find a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intended key resides in a nested `NSDictionary` object, so you can't retrieve it using:

```
NSDictionary *wind = [dico objectForKey:@"windspeedMiles"];
NSLog(@"The current windspeedMiles is : %@", wind);
```

Use:

```
NSDictionary *wind = [dico[@"data"][@"condition"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"The current windspeedMiles is : %@", wind[@"windspeedMiles"]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I want ! It works fine, don't down vote !

Comment: @Viny76: I know the answer is correct, and the downvoter is also know the answer is fine. There are some people, when they get enough reputation, they start their sadist mentality and downvote everyone, particularly new SO users. Can't say anything on that. I'm happy to hear that it worked for you :)

Comment: More directly (and less readable) [[[[dico objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"windspeedMiles"]

Comment: @bl4stwave Last question : If I want to access to "value" in "weatherIconUrl" (enter in another curly braces and square braces too), how can I make that ?

Comment: @Viny76: From answer use the wind object, then `wind[@"weatherIconUrl"][0][@"value"];`

Comment: @Viny76 try to copy-paste your JSON string here: http://jsoneditoronline.org that allow you to display the tree structure of it. However, you can get it directly `[[[[[[dico objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"value"]`

Comment: @bl4stwave So perfect with this URL, I've understood how to access in curly and square braces, THANKS !!!

Answer (score 1):

To grab that specific value in the structure you posted, you would access:

```
[[[[dico objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"current_condition"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"windspeedMiles"]
```

You just need to look at your structure. When you get your dictionary with the `JSONObjectWithData` it will give you an `NSDictionary` for every set of curly braces, and an `NSArray` for every set of square ones.

Because everything in your JSON is a sub-object of "Data", I would recommend creating your original `NSDictionary` as:

```
NSDictionary *dico = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil] objectForKey:@"data"];
```

This way you don't have to keep referencing the "data" dictionary.

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote ? His answer is correct right ?